# Powershell encoded command variables evaluation before execution (ServiceNow, Invoke-WMIMethod)

Tags: powershell, execution, servicenow

I have an issue with powershell scriptblock executed by ServiceNow MID Server on target host. 
Target host is running SQL server where I need to execute some PS Script running SQL commands and post process results (using JDBC activity is not valid in this case).

So I am running powershell on MID server (some kind of proxy, for these who are not familiar with ServiceNow) and I am needed to execute PS script using Encoded command via Invoke-WMIMethod cmdlet (**I cannot use Invoke-Command**, due to disabled PS remoting - no way to enable that due to company policies) like below:

```
$Bytes=[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($CallArgumentsBlock)
# Command block is passed as encoded command
$EncodedCommand=[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)

$WMIArgs=@{
        Class='win32_process'
        Name='Create'
        ComputerName=$computer
        ArgumentList="powershell -EncodedCommand $EncodedCommand"
        ErrorAction='SilentlyContinue'
        Credential=$cred
    }

    Invoke-WmiMethod @WMIArgs | Out-Null
```

Issue is that I need to push into $EncodedCommand pre-evaluated variables. Example of script block:

```
$CallArgumentsBlock={
    Param(
    [string] $SQLServer = "$inputSQLServer",  #SQL Server Name running on host
    [string] $SQLDBName = "$inputSQLDBName",  #SQL DB name
    [string] $InputData = "$inputInputData",  #JSON string holding data processed by PS+SQL
    [string] $ResultFolderPath = "$OutputPath_forSQL" #File path where to output results cause WMI can not return output of invoked command
    )

    $ProcessData = ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject $InputData

    #For each object call sql...
...
*PS code*
...
}
```

- So what should be powershell way to do it?
- Does anybody suggest better ServiceNow based solution?

**Thanks a lot for your answers!**

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is to remove the Param() statement, and just list the variables and set the values when creating the script block, any reason this wouldn't work?

```
$CallArgumentsBlock={
[string] $SQLServer = "$inputSQLServer"  #SQL Server Name running on host
[string] $SQLDBName = "$inputSQLDBName"  #SQL DB name
[string] $InputData = "$inputInputData"  #JSON string holding data processed by PS+SQL
[string] $ResultFolderPath = "$OutputPath_forSQL" #File path where to output results cause WMI can not return output of invoked command

$ProcessData = ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject $InputData

#For each object call sql...
...
*PS code*
...
}
```